# Update a table column by removing string characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a phone number column in an Oracle 11g table where I need to remove all instances of the following from the numbers:

```
(0)
```

so example would be:  `+44 (0)1223 123456` -> `+44 1223 123456`

How can I write an update statement to find the zero in parenthesis and remove it from each table row?
The `(0)` always is in the same position on all rows if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `REPLACE()` function:

```
update tablename
set phonecol = replace(phonecol, '(0)')
```

If the table is big, and only some of the rows will be updated, add the following to keep the transaction size down:

```
where phonecol like '%(0)%'
```

Comment: You don't need to use '' , just ignore that part of the expression

Comment: @JohnHC, thanks for the tip. (I don't know Oracle that well.)

Answer (score 0):

Try (for Oracle)

```
REPLACE(telno,'(0)') as Telno
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update tablename
  set phonecol = regexp_replace( phonecol ,'[(0)]') 
where phonecol like '%(0)%' ;
```

For eg you can try selecting using below:

```
select '+44 (0)1223 123456',regexp_replace( '+44 (0)1223 123456','[(0)]') 
from dual;
```